# Where is the mistake in this integral?

Tags: integration

Consider the following simple integral.
\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{1}{2x}\,dx.
\end{align*}
Now, I would usually work as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{1}{2x}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln x+C.
\end{align*}
However, I thought I would try:
\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{1}{2x}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{2}{2x}\,dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln 2x+C.
\end{align*}
I suppose this is incorrect. Why? Perhaps I should not use the same letter $C$ for both cases?

Comment: $\ln{2x} = \ln{2} + \ln{x}$. You see now why both are correct?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2x)+C=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(2)+\ln(x))+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)+C_1,$ where $C_1$ is just a different constant: $C_1=C+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$.

Comment: It's correct because both answers differ by a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not incorrect. Remember that indefinite integral is defined *only up* to an additive constant, and here in fact

$$\frac12\log 2x +C=\frac12\log x+\frac12\log 2+C$$

So again, the difference is **only** the addition of a constant, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: after the rules of logarithm we get $$\ln(2x)=\ln(2)+\ln(x)$$